# Regex find-replace to format a hierarchical tree to multiple lines?

Tags: regex, string, replace, find, sublimetext2

I have hierarchical trees whose structures are represented via parentheses, each tree fits a single line:

```
( ( ( A , B ) , ( C , D ) ) , E )
```

One can systematically and consistently re-arrange the trees to span multiple lines, forming more intuitive diagrams:

```
(
 (
  (
   A
   ,
   B
  )
  ,
  (
   C
   ,
   D
  )
 )
,
E
)
```

I am open to alternative suggestions - but my question is more specifically:

**Could somebody suggest a regular expression I can use (e.g. via Sublime Text 2's Find-Replace) to convert a single line version of the tree into a more intuitive multi-line version?**

The answer would ideally include an expression for the "Find" field and an expression for the "Replace" field.

Comment: Regular expressions are not well suited for parsing recursive structures like this. I'd suggest you try one of those alternatives.

Comment: Thanks @p.s.w.g - I admit the multi-line version I showed above is rather complex, but given that a more simple (yet sensible) alternative was given would you say it is impossible to achieve such a conversion using just regex?

Comment: I wouldn't rule it out. Many regex engines have extensions which help to process recursive structions (PHP has [recursive patterns](http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php), .NET has [balancing groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bs2twtah(v=vs.110).aspx#balancing_group_definition)), but they are generally cumbersome and difficult to use. I have no idea what engine Sublime Text uses or if it could somehow be made to produce this output. I wouldn't bet on it, though.

Comment: Hi @p.s.w.g, check my answer below, is using *recursive patterns* as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

The problem have no solution in the context of Sublimetext2... But Google and searches points here, and @p.s.w.g suggested PHP solution using [reference recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php). About this new context, the answer is **"yes"** we have a solution for the problem of *"pretty hierarchy by regular expression"*

### Proof of concept using PHP

The solution is possible with a "double recurrence",

```
 $txt = '( ( ( A , B ) , ( C , D ) ) , E )';
 print "\n-- starting with: $txt\n";
 print parse_parentheses($txt,' ',' ')."\n";


 function parse_parentheses($txt,$sep='  ',$sepStep='  ') {
    $stop='('; // must be compatible with the kernel regex
    return preg_replace_callback(
        '#\( (   ( (?>[^()]+) | (?R) )*   ) \)#sx', // kernel
        function ($m) use ($sep,$sepStep,$stop) {
            $r = trim($m[1]); // trim optional
            if (strpos($r,$stop) === false)
              return "\n$sep($r)";
            else 
              return "\n$sep(".parse_parentheses($r,"$sepStep$sep")."\n$sep)";
        },
        $txt
    );
}
```

The kernel piece is the regular expression, the recurrences are

1. the  [reference recursive](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.recursive.php) in the regular expression, see `(?R)`;
2. the usual [recursive function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)#Recursive_procedures), to the per-branches loops.

The result of the algorithm above is:

```
-- starting with: ( ( ( A , B ) , ( C , D ) ) , E )

 ( 
  ( 
   ( A , B ) , 
   ( C , D ) 
  ) , E 
 )
```

Other example:

```
-- starting with: ab(cd ( X ) ) e ( Y )
ab
  (cd 
    (X)
  ) e 
  (Y)
```